# multiple vs single database for one system

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, database-design

im a very new php developer and im developing my very first system for an education institute and its contain staffs, administration, students, students performance and payment details.

I'm not sure on what is the best approach in database. Should I use a single database for all data or need to create multiple databases for mentioned contains.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: At first it might seem convenient to split off different categories into their own databases. I was guilty of this when I first started out, making a "Customer Service" database, and then a "QA Document" database, a "Products" database, a "Website" database and so on. I thought this is great, I can create users that only have access to 1 database! But in the end it just lead to a lot more work having everything splintered like that, and it was way more of a pain merging everything back into 1 database without breaking things than it would have been just to design it that way from the start

Comment: 1 database is preferred.  Items like staffs, administration, students, students performance and payment details will be tables in the DB

Comment: 1 database. You will get to dive into the world of Group permissions, ACL's, and user roles. You will appreciate learning this when approaching future projects as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what do you mean by a database to begin with:

- is it a schema within one database?
- is it a single non clustered instance?
- is it one cluster with multiple instances? 
  or is it something logical and you are not really asking about physical characteristics of your data storage mechanism.

Assuming the requirements stem from the school work assignment,  one database, one schema and multiple tables will be enough.

If you need to think of high reliability, redundancy, fail-overs - that would be a totally different answer most likely suggesting multiple database instances.

If you are concerned with high-scale, that would yet be another answer, possibly suggesting clustered database environment.

In short, what are your requirements, how many records, how many users, how critical is it to have database down for prolonged number of hours, or days?

Answer (score 2):

A single database containing multiple tables would be best, imo.

So, a database called "institute" or something that broadly encompasses the data.
In it, you have a table for each of user, performance, and payment. User should contain a row specifying whether the user is a staff member, admin, or student. Payment and performance should contain a field linked to the user ID.

Answer (score 2):

A single db with many tables will do. It will also be more portable, as some low cost hosting may give you only one db or add price for another one (rarely nowadays). It will be definitely more practical as all your SQL will be simpler.

One reason you may use another db is if you clone the first one and use it to show updates to the site contents to editors before they are actually shown to the public. What I mean is that when an administrator or an editor writes a new post or updates info, you insert it in db1. A copy of the site can show the preview reading db1, then administrators press a publish button and all you have to do is clone db1 to db2 with one single sql instruction. This way you have a "staging" site to test entries, and a public site for everyone else. You can do this also with duplicate tables of course but in this case, two dbs feels cleaner and simpler to me.